# Windows Phone not load local JSON file with $getJSON

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm now implement Windows Phone with Phonegap Cordova 2.0.0 and Jquery Mobile 1.1.1 final
and I'm be stuck with using local JSON file due to Window Phone Emulator not load JSON data 
to `<select>` element while both iOS and Android emulators run smoothly. And this is my snippet code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-icon-pack-2.1.2-fa.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/json2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            function changeBaseAmount() {
                alert($('#baseAmount').val());
            }

        $.getJSON('json/currencies.json',
            function (data) {
                alert("get json");
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                    $('#currency1').append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>");

                    $('#currency2').append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>");

               });

           });



    </script>
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <!-- Home Page -->
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">

                <h1>Convert Currency</h1>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="wrench" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            </div> 

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">

                <div id="baseAmountDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="baseAmount">Amount:</label>
                    <input id="baseAmount" type="text" value="" onchange="changeBaseAmount()"></input>
                </div>
                <div id="currency1Div" data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="currency1">Currency From:</label>
                    <select id="currency1" onchange="changeCurrency1()">
                        <option value="ZZ">Please Select Currency From</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="currency2Div" data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="currency2">Currency To:</label>
                    <select id="currency2" onchange="changeCurrency2()">
                        <option value="ZZ">Please Select Currency To</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="resultAmountDiv" data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="resultAmount">Result:</label>
                    <input id="resultAmount" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: silver"></input>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b"></i></div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cordova for WP7 has its own implementation of XHR requests in order to support fetching local data. See the following:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-208

You might have to use `$.ajax` in order for this to work properly.

Comment: WP8 emulator, same issue while trying to read local xml file, I get error message "Not connect.\n Verify Network." ... my call ... $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "res/raw/puzzle_data.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml){ ...